# terraform aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm dynamic dimension key error

Tags: terraform

Wondering if it's possible to use a dynamic evaluated list element in a terraform aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm dimension name.

using a locals list like this with the idea to create x amount of cloudwatch alarms.

```
locals {
 alarm_list = ['service1-status', 'service2-status2', service3-status3']
}
```

in my resouce block for aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm

```
dimensions = {
     "${element(split("-", local.alarms_list[count.index]), 0)}" = 
     "${element(split("-", local.alarms_list[count.index]), 1)}"
```

}

this is the output im getting with tf plan.

```
  + aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.alarm[0]
      id:                                                                   <computed>
      actions_enabled:                                                      "true"
      alarm_description:                                                    "response codes from nginx status"
      alarm_name:                                                           "nginx-status-alarm"
      arn:                                                                  <computed>
      comparison_operator:                                                  "GreaterThanThreshold"
      dimensions.${element(split("-", local.alarms_list[count.index]), 0)}: ""
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I not use aws\_lambda\_function datasource inside aws\_lambda\_alias routing\_config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890700/why-can-i-not-use-aws-lambda-function-datasource-inside-aws-lambda-alias-routing)

Comment: The question isn't the same as the linked duplicate but the answer is. You can't use interpolation on the left hand side of a key by default in Terraform < 0.12. The answer explains how it will work in 0.12 and provides a workaround for 0.11 too.

Comment: Ahh yeah,, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple in terraform 0.12 using map [for-expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions), e.g.

```
  dimensions = {
    for value in local.alarm_list :
      element(split("-", value), 0) => element(split("-", value), 1)
  }
```